# Perl xml containing quotes

Tags: perl, tomcat7, nagios

I'm updating my nagios plugin that monitors tomcat thread utilization for tomcat7 and am having a problem with a value enclosed in "quotes".

The relevant XML from Dumper:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'connector' => {
                         '"ajp-bio-8009"' => {
                                             'requestInfo' => {
                                                              'maxTime' => '0',
                                                              'errorCount' => '0',
                                                              'bytesSent' => '0',
                                                              'processingTime' => '0',
                                                              'requestCount' => '0',
                                                              'bytesReceived' => '0'
                                                            },
                                             'workers' => {},
                                             'threadInfo' => {
                                                             'currentThreadCount' => '0',
                                                             'maxThreads' => '500',
                                                             'currentThreadsBusy' => '0'
                                                           }
                                           }
                       },
```

Relevent Perl:

```
 $max = $xml->{'connector'}->{'"ajp-bio-8009"'}->{'threadInfo'}->{'maxThreads'};
 $current = $xml->{'connector'}->{'"ajp-bio-8009"'}->{'threadInfo'}->{'currentThreadCount'};
 $busy = $xml->{'connector'}->{'"ajp-bio-8009"'}->{'threadInfo'}->{'currentThreadsBusy'};
```

But unfortunately this doesn't appear to be working as I am not populating any values for $max, $current, or $busy.

Full XML as requested:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="/manager/xform.xsl" ?>
<status>
    <jvm>
        <memory free="70176624" total="165605376" max="2534080512"/>
        <memorypool name="Eden Space" type="Heap memory" usageInit="12582912"
            usageCommitted="45744128" usageMax="699072512" usageUsed="23043760"/>
        <memorypool name="Survivor Space" type="Heap memory" usageInit="1572864"
            usageCommitted="5701632" usageMax="87359488" usageUsed="5545632"/>
        <memorypool name="Tenured Gen" type="Heap memory" usageInit="31588352"
            usageCommitted="114159616" usageMax="1747648512" usageUsed="66839360"/>
        <memorypool name="Code Cache" type="Non-heap memory" usageInit="2555904"
            usageCommitted="5505024" usageMax="50331648" usageUsed="5395264"/>
        <memorypool name="Perm Gen" type="Non-heap memory" usageInit="21757952"
            usageCommitted="51904512" usageMax="1048576000" usageUsed="51657456"/>
    </jvm>
    <connector name='"ajp-bio-8009"'>
        <threadInfo maxThreads="500" currentThreadCount="0" currentThreadsBusy="0"/>
        <requestInfo maxTime="0" processingTime="0" requestCount="0" errorCount="0"
            bytesReceived="0" bytesSent="0"/>
        <workers/>
    </connector>
    <connector name='"http-bio-8080"'>
        <threadInfo maxThreads="200" currentThreadCount="10" currentThreadsBusy="1"/>
        <requestInfo maxTime="1596" processingTime="4078" requestCount="416" errorCount="64"
            bytesReceived="0" bytesSent="639904"/>
        <workers>
            <worker stage="R" requestProcessingTime="0" requestBytesSent="0"
                requestBytesReceived="0" remoteAddr="&#63;" virtualHost="&#63;" method="&#63;"
                currentUri="&#63;" currentQueryString="&#63;" protocol="&#63;"/>
            <worker stage="R" requestProcessingTime="0" requestBytesSent="0"
                requestBytesReceived="0" remoteAddr="&#63;" virtualHost="&#63;" method="&#63;"
                currentUri="&#63;" currentQueryString="&#63;" protocol="&#63;"/>
            <worker stage="R" requestProcessingTime="0" requestBytesSent="0"
                requestBytesReceived="0" remoteAddr="&#63;" virtualHost="&#63;" method="&#63;"
                currentUri="&#63;" currentQueryString="&#63;" protocol="&#63;"/>
            <worker stage="S" requestProcessingTime="3" requestBytesSent="0"
                requestBytesReceived="0" remoteAddr="38.88.49.38" virtualHost="blah01.blah.com"
                method="GET" currentUri="/manager/status" currentQueryString="XML=true"
                protocol="HTTP/1.1"/>
            <worker stage="R" requestProcessingTime="0" requestBytesSent="0"
                requestBytesReceived="0" remoteAddr="&#63;" virtualHost="&#63;" method="&#63;"
                currentUri="&#63;" currentQueryString="&#63;" protocol="&#63;"/>
            <worker stage="R" requestProcessingTime="0" requestBytesSent="0"
                requestBytesReceived="0" remoteAddr="&#63;" virtualHost="&#63;" method="&#63;"
                currentUri="&#63;" currentQueryString="&#63;" protocol="&#63;"/>
        </workers>
    </connector>
</status>
```

Comment: Can you show the original XML?

Comment: Try debugging node by node. For example, print Dumper $xml->{'connector'}->{'"ajp-bio-8009"'} and then next node until to last one. And check at where you are missing value.

Comment: I tried it by just using the hash, as output by Dumper and I was able to get the data.  How is the XML being parsed?  `XML::Simple` or similar module?

Comment: In future please format your XML so it's not all on one line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your xml is fine. You already got your result from the dumper. Perhaps you don't quest your acutal xml object.

If you look at the dumper output, and just take it to check again than you get the values you want:

```
$max = $VAR1->{'connector'}->{'"ajp-bio-8009"'}->{'threadInfo'}->{'maxThreads'};
$current = $VAR1->{'connector'}->{'"ajp-bio-8009"'}->{'threadInfo'}->{'currentThreadCount'};
$busy = $VAR1->{'connector'}->{'"ajp-bio-8009"'}->{'threadInfo'}->{'currentThreadsBusy'};

print $max."\n"; print $current."\n"; print $busy."\n";
```

Which gives:

```
500
0
0
```

So, I conclude, that your *$xml* object is somehow not the object you want to analyze (or it is a sup- or substructure of the reference you want to traverse).